# Bootstrap и padding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, padding

Зачем в Bootstrap нужны `padding`?
В каждом классе `col` есть `padding-left` и `padding-right` 15px.
Я их тупо убрал, поставил 0рх, на что это может повлиять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как `bootstrap` изначально предназначен для быстрого прототипирования макетов, то смею думаю, что данные отступы предназначены для того, чтобы можно было без лишних заморочек добавлять контент в блоки с классом `col-*`, не боясь, что содержимое блоков начнет "наезжать" друг на друга. Эти отступы формируют визуальные края контента, так что можете смело обнулять их и задавать свои, если в этом есть необходимость.
Всё же, считаю, удобнее будет создать класс, который их будет обнулять (`.nopadding { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}`), и добавлять его по мере необходимости, т.к. встроенные достаточно удобны.

Comment: Спасибо, понял!